# Algorithm to check if quadrilateral is convex

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-geometry

I am looking for an algorithm to check if a quadrilateral is convex. I am sure that the quadrilateral is not self-intersecting, so I only need to check if it is convex or concave.
One method would be to check if any interior angle is larger than π. However, I am struggling to calculate the interior angle. Using the dot product just yields an angle between two lines, not necessarily the interior angle.
Note that I intend to apply the algorithm to thousands of quadrilaterals programatically, so plotting is out of scope (and error prone to begin with).

Here is an example of a quadrilateral I would like to classify as convex or concave. The corners A, B, C and D are given in order.
$A = \begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\-2\end{pmatrix}$,
$B = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\3\\-1/7\end{pmatrix}$,
$C = \begin{pmatrix}4\\2\\-12/7\end{pmatrix}$,
$D = \begin{pmatrix}8\\1\\-20/7\end{pmatrix}$

**EDIT**
Let's start first with the assumption that the quadrilateral is planar and I will deal with the slight skwewedness later, maybe in a follow up question.

**EDIT2**
I just realized how ill defined my wish to include skew quadrilaterals was. Those are not even uniquely defined by 4 points.

Comment: For every sides, check if the other two points are on opposite sides.

Comment: This looked like an easy question to answer until you revealed that you are working in three dimensions! I think that makes it impossible to answer. For a start, you have to define what it means to say that a [skew quadrilateral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewQuadrilateral.html) is convex.

Comment: @TonyK ok, let's focus on the planar case then and I will see if that works well enough for me. The skewdness in my application is very minor and ignored for the most part, but renders the assumption of a perfect 2π interior angle useless.

Comment: @TonyK my definition of convex would be that the skewed quadrilateral is convex if its projection in the "correct" plane is convex. The correct plane would be the one that minimizes the distances of all points from that plane. But as per my edit, assume that the quadrilateral is planar to begin with.

Comment: If it's planar, my method in the first comment will work.

Comment: @Hypernova indeed, it should work, though I find the solution of Alex K easier to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the vertices in order, look at the cross products of the vectors of successive edges; with vertices $v_1 \dots v_4$ you'd look at $(v_3-v_2)\times (v_2-v_1)$ etc. These cross products will all point along the polygon's normal. For a convex polygon, they'll all point in the same direction.

You can simplify this more, knowing that the cross product $a \times a =0$.